# stub a method in mock bean in spring integration context

Tags: java, spring, mockito, spring-integration

I am trying to test a spring integration set up
my unit test is as follows,

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = { SIContext2Config.class })
public class FileMoverTest extends GenericTest {

@Test
public void testFileMover() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    int total = 2;
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Message<OfferMessage> msg = (Message<OfferMessage>) hdfsReadyChannel.receive(2000);
        System.out.println("Message # " + i + " received:" + msg.getPayload().getOfferFile().getAbsolutePath());
        n++;
    }
    Assert.state(n == total);
}
```

The context class is as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class SIContext2Config { 

@Mock
private FsShell fsh;

@InjectMocks
@Mock
private MoveToHdfs fileMover;

@Bean
public Ingester ingester() {
    return new Ingester(fileMover);
}

@Mock
private Ingester ingester;

@Bean
public FilePickupHandler filePickupHandler() {
    return new FilePickupHandler();
}
}
```

Now, here is what I am trying to do:
The Ingester bean has a method called handle(), inside which the MoveToHdfs object fileMover runs and calls move().

```
public OfferMessage handle(Message<OfferMessage> msg) {
    // get hive directory path
    String remotePath = msg.getPayload().getOfferComponent().getHiveDirectory();
    String localFile = msg.getPayload().getOfferFile().getAbsolutePath();
    LOGGER.debug("Moving file {} to remote path:{}", localFile, remotePath);

    if (!fileMover.move(localFile, remotePath, true)) {
            throw new SomeException();
    }

    return msg.getPayload();
}
```

I just want that to return true.
But I can't figure out where to "stub" that, or how to stub that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't rework that `fileMover` to the `@Bean`?

```
@Bean
public MoveToHdfs fileMover() {
    MoveToHdfs fileMover = Mockito.mock(MoveToHdfs.class);
    when(fileMover.move(anyString(), anyString(), anyBoolean())).thenReturn(true);
    return fileMover;
}
```

Comment: perfect, thanks. this is much cleaner than implementing a BeanPostProcessor which is where I was going next.